# Lightbox is messing up my jquery

Tags: jquery, lightbox, lightbox2

I have a problem with my lightbox...it works fine but I also have jQuery in my code and for some reason it messes up the jquery..why is it doing this?

Here are my script tags...

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.willruppelglass.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.willruppelglass.com/js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.willruppelglass.com/js/prototype.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.willruppelglass.com/js/scriptaculous.js?load=effects,builder"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.willruppelglass.com/js/lightbox.js"></script>
```

and here is my jQuery...

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".galleryNavToggle").on("mouseenter", function (event) {
        $('#headerNavGallery, #headerNavInfo').hide();
        $("#headerNavGallery").show();
    });

    $(".galleryNavInfoToggle").on("mouseenter", function (event) {
        $('#headerNavGallery, #headerNavInfo').hide();
        $("#headerNavInfo").show();
    });


$(window).bind('load', function() {  

    var div_height = $("#content").height();
    $(".leftSideBar").css("height", div_height);

    var div_height = $("#content").height();
    $(".rightSideBar").css("height", div_height);

});



</script>
```

I dont know why its messing everything up :( any help would be apperiated. Thanks

- J

Comment: What do you mean by "messing everything up"? You're including jQuery twice, remove one.

Comment: You are linking jQuery twice, and also linking prototype. Are you sure lightbox is the real culprit here?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why not just use a jquery lightbox plugin, like slimbox? Oh, and jQuery.noConflict() may be your answer.

Comment: not really a mess, its just my jQuery code wont work anymore when I put in the lightbox script tags

Comment: I tried jQuery.noConflict()  and it didnt work :(

Answer (score 2):

You dont need to put `jquery-1.7.1.js` and `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` in your page.

The `jquery-1.7.1.min.js` is the minified version of `jquery-1.7.1.js`. The content is the same. Use only `jquery-1.7.1.min.js`

### Update

You forgot to wait until the DOM is fully builded. Try this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $(".galleryNavToggle").on("mouseenter", function (event) {
            $('#headerNavGallery, #headerNavInfo').hide();
            $("#headerNavGallery").show();
        });

        // other content
    }
</script>
```

Comment: i took out jquery-1.7.1.js still having the same issue.

Comment: What is your issue ? What you mean with "messing everything up" ?

Comment: what I meant is that my jquery script wont run if I have the lightbox script tags in there

Comment: gotta get going for now, but I will check later...thanks for you're time :)

Answer (score 0):

It is the protoype.js which is messing up jQuery.

Also why are you inlcuding unminified and minified jQuery file? Only one is required preferably the minified version.

Comment: I took out the extra jQuery script and took out protoype.js my jquery runs now but lightbox is not working now.